# Continuity of fractional part function for negative integers

Tags: calculus, continuity, fractional-part

Given a function $f(x)=frac(x^2)-(frac(x))^2$

We have to check continuity at $x=-2$

I know that $frac(x)= x-[x]$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function less than or equal to x.

Checking continuity -

$f(-2)=0$

$f(-2^+)=frac(4^+)-(frac(-2^+))^2=0$

But according to the textbook, right-hand limit should be 1. And hence the function should be discontinuous. Where am I wrong? I used the same way to check continuity at $x=2$ and it came out to be continuous which is correct according to the textbook.

Comment: What is the definition of $[x]$?

Comment: $[x]$ is the greatest integer function.

Comment: Oops. Yes, less than or equal to x.

Comment: How do you justify your calculation of $f(-2+)$?

Comment: $frac(4^+)-(frac(-2^+))^2=4-[4^+]-((-2)-[-2^+])^2=4-4-((-2)-(-2))^2=0-0=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check continuity you want to evaluate the function close to (say, just above) $-2$. If $x$ is just above $-2$ then $x^2$ is just *below* $4$. So $\mathrm{frac}(x^2)$ is a number just below $1$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example. What do you mean by above? Greater or less than -2?

Comment: @DevanshKumar Greater than. Let $x = -2 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Okay say we plug in $-1.99$, then we get $frac(3.96)=0.96=1(approx)$. Right?

Comment: @DevanshKumar That's right. So can you now spot the error in your calculation in the comments?